# Is there a Informix Test Framework available? Or any kind of way to test informix screens?

Tags: automated-testing, test-automation-framework, testing-framework

I am looking for a way to test Informix 4GL screens, such as this one in blue from the left.

[image]

I have tested similar screens like this, in Mainframe systems using Jagacy Framework. The tests were positional, regarding the automation coding. There were no xpaths available, considering it is not a web test.

If anyone knows any framework or way to test it, I would really appreciate.

Answer (score -1):

This [article](https://community.microfocus.com/t5/Unified-Functional-Testing-User/HP-UFT-12-on-Informix-4GL-and-Mainframe/td-p/576167) mentions using HP UFT/QTP with the Terminal-Emulator add-in for testing informix 4GL specifically.

I'm not familiar with testing mainframe screens, but hopefully this will make some sense.

Comment: This link guided me to focus on UFT tool to proceed with those tests.But, even 'those' who tried to configure this add-in for terminal, did not succeed.
Thanks anyway for your post, but I still did not find a final solution for this. I am still looking for. Also hear about AutoIT here https://www.progresstalk.com/threads/best-testing-tool-to-be-used-with-openedge-4gl-client.143633 , but the guy is giving up on using it as well cuz did not recognize the elements in screen.